# jQuery colorbox resize

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the jQuery plugin ColorBox.

Inside of my file have use jquery hide & slideToggle.

I need to change colorbox's height when I click and slide hidden div.

I have tried `colorbox resize` or `$("#ajax_container").height($("#a").height());`

Both are not working, is there any way to do this?

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#a").hide();

        $("#click_a").click(function(){
            $("#a").slideToggle(200);
            $.colorbox.resize();
        });
    });
</script>

<style>
    #ajax_container {
        width:680px;
        min-height:400px;
        overflow:hidden;
        background:white;
    }
    #a {
        width:500px;
        height:5500px;
        background:red;
        margin-bottom:50px;
    }
</style>

<div id="ajax_container">
    <a id="click_a" href="#">Click me</a>
    <div id="a"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try to call "$.colorbox.resize();" in the **complete** callback of "slideToggle"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.colorbox.resize({height: 6000});
```

add this into it, should be work.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function(){
    var custom_timeout = ( function() {
        var timers = {};
        return function ( callback, ms, uniqueId ) {
            if ( !uniqueId ) {
                uniqueId = "Don't call this twice without a uniqueId";
            }
            if ( timers[uniqueId] ) {
                clearTimeout ( timers[uniqueId] );
            }
            timers[uniqueId] = setTimeout( callback, ms );
          };
    })(); 
    $(".group1").colorbox({rel:'group1', width:"80%" }); 
    $( window ).resize( function(){
        custom_timeout(function(){
            if( $('#cboxOverlay' ).css( 'visibility' ) ){
                $(".group1").colorbox.resize({ innerWidth:'80%' });
            }
        }, 500 );
    }); 
});
```

Comment: I removed your dead link.